# How do I use mod_rewrite to change the path and filename of a URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to take the url:
http://www.mydomain.com/signup-12345

And actually give them:
http://www.mydomain.com/signup/?aff=12345

I have NO history with mod_rewrite, HELP!

Comment: mydomain.com is owned by somebody.  example.com is reserved for examples like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that I found relatively hard to find out was how to do the reverse of what you are doing, whereby you need to find out the value of part of the query string.

So for example:

If you wanted to rewrite the Url:
http://www.example.com/signup-**old**-script.**asp**?**aff**=12345

to:
http://www.example.com/signup-**new**-script.**php**?**affID**=12345

you could use:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string}& ^aff=((.+&)|&)$   
RewriteRule ^/signup-old-script.asp$    /signup-new-script.php?affID=%2 [L,R]
```

Notice the **%** sign in the rewrite rule instead of the **$** sign.

I had to do this so I could support old flash maps in a new site that had links to ".cfm" files with an ID in the query string.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

RewriteRule ^/signup-(\d+)/$ /signup/?aff=$1 [I]

Comment: What does this [I] flag stands for? Couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Freelancer The flags aren't case sensitive. [l] is the same as [L]

Answer (score 1):

As far i know,

*flag causes the RewriteCond to be ignored.* - for "Ignore case" - from `IsapiRewrite` version 2