# How to take PHP input parameter from URL like this www.domain.com/item/ABC123

Tags: php, friendly-url, input-parameters

I the want user to visit www.domain.com/item/ABC123

---

As you can see here ABC123 should be the input parameter

like this www.domain.com/item/?Id=ABC123

Under /item/ there is an index.php file, that will take an Id input parameter, how do I pass the input parameter value from www.domain.com/item/ABC123 to the id input parameter of the index.php file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache Mod-Rewrite Primers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122097/apache-mod-rewrite-primers) and probably 100 more threads on mod_rewrite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use mod_rewrite to change the path and filename of a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105308/how-do-i-use-mod-rewrite-to-change-the-path-and-filename-of-a-url)

Answer (score 1):

using **[.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html)** file

add rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/item/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ /item/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,E]
```

Answer (score 0):

use mod_rewrite

E.g.
http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Answer (score 0):

You'll need url rewriting. 
Basicaly, you'll have an .htaccess with a rewrite rule which will transforms your URL.
For instance, `www.domain.com/item/some/things/ABC123` into `www.domain.com/item/index.php?queryString=some/things/ABC123` and your PHP will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this should work:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

index.php

```
$uri = preg_replace("#(/+)#","/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$uri = array_shift(explode("/",$uri));
```

now, `$uri` is an array of each portion of the URI.  so /a/b/c becomes:

```
array(
    0 => "a",
    1 => "b",
    2 => "c",
)
```

Comment: Note, this is a general solution with untested code to enable quick and painless uri routing in a PHP application.